# Search a database to update the results

Tags: php, mysql

I am taking a users input and storing it in a database, however I want to be able to update the records if a user adds more information. So I want to search the database find the server with the same name and update the the last downtime and the number of downtimes.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Username", "Password","Test_downtime");

    if (!$connect) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }else
    {
        echo "Connected successfully\n";
    }

$servername = $_GET["server_name"];
$downtime = $_GET["downtime"];

$time_now = time();
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Test_downtime`.`Downtime` WHERE `Server_Name` = '$servername'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            // If no downtime have been reported before
            if ($row[0] == 0){
                $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `Test_downtime`.`Downtime` (ID, Server_name, First_downtime, Last_downtime, Num_of_downtime,Total_downtime) VALUES (NULL, '$servername', '$time_now','$time_now',1,'$downtime'); ");
                if ($sql==true) {
                    echo $servername . " has has its first downtime recorded\n";
                } 
            }



            //If users is already in the database
            else{
                $numdowntime = ($row["Num_of_downtime"] + 1);
                $id = ($row["ID"]);
                $sqlupdate = "UPDATE `Test_downtime`.`Downtime` SET `Num_of_downtime` = $numdowntime, `Last_downtime` = now() WHERE `Server_Name` = '$servername'";

                 if ($sqlupdate == TRUE) {
                    echo "Oh No! " . $servername . " has had ". $numdowntime ." of downtimes" ;
                }   
            }
?>
```

The program works fine if the server is not already in the database, the problems arise if the server is already in the database. I get the message saying it has been updated yet nothing happens to the database. How do i make it so it search and updates the records for the searched item.

Comment: So the `UPDATE` command is returning success but not updating the record(s)?  What is the actual text of the SQL command you're executing at run time?  What happens when you execute it manually in MySQL?

Comment: the `if ($sqlupdate == TRUE)` is always non-strict `true` since the `$sqlupdate` is non-empty query string.

Comment: @nasher99 take a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So nothing append since you **do not** execute the sql statement ^^

Take a look here :

```
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE `Test_downtime`.`Downtime` SET `Num_of_downtime` = $numdowntime, `Last_downtime` = now() WHERE `Server_Name` = '$servername'";
```

You need to use :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlupdate);
```

Just after it in order to execute it.

Or at least change it to

```
$sqlupdate = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `Test_downtime`.`Downtime` SET `Num_of_downtime` = $numdowntime, `Last_downtime` = now() WHERE `Server_Name` = '$servername'" );
```

Btw there is other problem but here is the main one [check out the other answer in order to found another one ]

Answer (score 0):

you are fetching the result as indexed array

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

and here you are accessing results as associative array

```
$numdowntime = ($row["Num_of_downtime"] + 1);
```

change your query to

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

use

```
mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

to checking if you have any data

change

```
if ($row[0] == 0){}
```

to

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) ==0){}
```

Comment: When I change it to this it always activates the if statment

Comment: use mysqli_num_rows($result); for checking

Comment: it is wrong since by default it returns both variants with `MYSQLI_BOTH`

Comment: @vSugumar I applied both changes as you said but it still doesnt fix the problem and when i echo $row it just returns Array

Comment: .. take a look at my answer @nasher99 you forget to execute the query

Comment: @kaldoran I've added that as well that was very useful i total forgot about that but the array problem still persists

Comment: use print_r($result); to know what data you have

Answer (score -1):

You miss the `mysqli_query()` function, which actually queries the database.

```
$sqlupdate = mysqli_query("
    UPDATE `Test_downtime`.`Downtime`
    SET `Num_of_downtime` = $numdowntime, `Last_downtime` = now()
    WHERE `Server_Name` = '$servername'"
);
```

Answer (score -1):

A good approach for increasing a count in a column is using SQL to increase that.

```
$sqlupdate = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `Test_downtime`.`Downtime` SET `Num_of_downtime` = (`Num_of_downtime` + 1), `Last_downtime` = now() WHERE `Server_Name` = '$servername'" );
```

This way you can skip your $numdowntime calculation, and the result is more accurate.

In your current setup, two users may fire the event at the same time, they both retrieve the same number from the database (ie. 9), both increasing it with one (ie. 10), and writing the same number in the database.
Making your count one short of the actual count.

SQL takes care of this for you by locking rows, and you are left with a more accurate result using less logic :)